# Como repetir todo o código ao fim da execução quando "While" repete apenas uma parte?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula o pagamento de uma pessoa baseada no número de horas e horas extras trabalhadas. A ideia é que ao fim da execução o usuário decida se quer calcular novamente ou encerrar o programa, mas quando seleciona a opção de tentar novamente somente as duas últimas linhas de códigos são executadas, não o código completo, como pode ser visto a seguir:

```
#Título: Pagamento por Horas
#Contador de pagamento baseado em horas regulares e horas extras trabalhadas

horas = 0
base = 0
resposta = 'S'

while resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's':
    while horas == 0:
        try:
            horas = int(input('Digite as horas trabalhadas: '))
        except:
            print('Por favor, digite uma entrada numérica! :)')
    global base
    while base == 0:
        try:
            base = int(input('Digite a base para o cálculo: '))
        except:
            print('Por favor, digite uma entrada numérica! :)')
    if horas > 40:
        horas_extras = float((horas-40)*(base*1.5))
        pagamento = (40*base)+horas_extras
    else:
        pagamento = horas*base
    print('O valor do pagamento será: {:.2f}'.format(pagamento))
    resposta = str(input('Para calcular novamente digite [S]'))
```

Já tentei isolar o código dentro de uma função para ver se tudo seria executado, mas não tive sucesso. Alguém sabe onde posso ter errado ou se há uma maneira de fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Coloque `horas = 0` e `base = 0` no inicio do primeiro laço `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque ao final a variavel horas vai ter o valor que você digitou e o bloco `while horas == 0` so vai ser executado se a variavel horas for igual a 0, a mesma coisa no bloco `while base == 0`. Tente:

```
    ...
    print('O valor do pagamento será: {:.2f}'.format(pagamento))
    resposta = str(input('Para calcular novamente digite [S]'))
    horas = 0
    base = 0
    ...
```

Comment: Agora funcionou o código. Tinha mesmo esquecido de voltar os valores pra zero pro bloco voltar a funcionar. Muito obrigado!